# Making a smaller JavaFX ComboBox

Tags: css, layout, combobox, javafx, size

I'm trying to make a smaller version of the ComboBox but the gap between the text and the arrow button is constant no matter what I do.

If I use the css:

```
.combo-box-base > *.arrow-button {
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 0;
    -fx-background-color: pink, pink, pink, pink;
}
```

the arrow button gets smaller but the ComboBox itself still have the same size, only increasing the gap between the arrow and text to compensate.

If I do

```
.combo-box > .list-cell {
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 0;
    -fx-border-insets: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

The combo get a smaller height but the width remain fixed.

Is there any way to make the preferred size of the combo smaller by reducing the size between the text and arrow?

[image: single entry combo]

Comment: How did you define the ComboBox in your code?

Comment: Well, nothing special. Just "new ComboBox()" and added the single text entry from the image. The CSS is set on the Scene.

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is quite old but i came across the same problem and wanted to solve it. So i started debugging the JavaFX code step by step to get an idea where the additional space comes from.
It took me longer than it should because i overlooked a small piece of code with a huge impact.

The class `ComboBoxListViewSkin` is by default responsible for the computation of the `ComboBox` width. Its compute method delegates the computation to the super class and the `prefWidth` method of the field `listView` and chooses the greater result.

```
/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override protected double computePrefWidth(double height, double topInset, double rightInset, double bottomInset, double leftInset) {
    double superPrefWidth = super.computePrefWidth(height, topInset, rightInset, bottomInset, leftInset);
    double listViewWidth = listView.prefWidth(height);
    double pw = Math.max(superPrefWidth, listViewWidth);

    reconfigurePopup();

    return pw;
}
```

The `listView` field is actually an instance of an `Anonymous Classes` extending `ListView` which does some `ComboBox` specific things and overrides some methods. One of these methods is `protected double computePrefWidth(double height)`. It contains the line which causes the problem with extra whitespace we cannot get rid of.

```
pw = Math.max(comboBox.getWidth(), skin.getMaxCellWidth(rowsToMeasure) + 30);
```

Adding 30 to the widest cell's width is exactly what we don't want. Because it's hard coded we cannot easily change it. I overlooked it at first glance causing some WTF moments when debugging the code.
Of course you can extend `ComboBoxListViewSkin` and override its `computePrefWidth` method but i think the default `ComboBoxListViewSkin` class should provide the possibility to change this extra whitespace easily. So I filed an [issue at GitHub](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/574#issue-486531544).

Comment: A bit late to the party, but still an issue. I tried following your guidance but could not overwrite the method. Could you provide an example of how to do this?
*note: skin.getMaxCellWidth is private

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the padding of .combox-box > .text-input ?
According to Oracles [ComboBox CSS documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#combobox), this could be another source of padding.
If you plan on developing more CSS-rules, maybe have a look at the CSS inspector of the SceneBuilder2 or use [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/). ScenicView also allows live-modification of the CSS, which significantly improves debugging speed.

Comment: Thanks. That one is just for editable combos I believe.

Comment: I do use SceneBuilder for these kind of things. I don't think it's optimal for the task, but it works OK. The docs are also used a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the Hgrow property ? you should set it in the layout manager for the combo box

`ComboBox field = new ComboBox();
 HBox.setHgrow(field, Priority.NEVER);`

Also check the preferred and maximum width you should set them to USE_COMPUTED_SIZE (in SceneBuilder, not sure how to do it by code).